# Возможно сделать трапецию с заливкой градиентом на чистом css?

Tags: css

Есть элемент дизайна в виде трапеции и заливкой градиентом. 
Трапецию можно заверстать через border. Но тогда их не залить градиентом. 
Реально ли вообще решить задачу с помощью css?

Элемент выглядит вот так: 
[image]

Например простейщая трапеция с помощью границ:

```css
.d11 {
height: 0; 
width: 100px;
border-bottom: 100px solid #FFE344;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<p class="d11">
</p>
```

Comment: что-то мне кажется, что у вашей "трапеции" грани не параллельны. куда проще решить задачу с помощью SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css 3д перспектива подойдет:

```css
.container {
  display:block;
  height:120px;
  perspective: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.block {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, #bb1caa, #251675 100%);
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform:rotatey(60deg)rotatex(10deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```